# What is the difference between ROSberry Pi builds?

Tags: ros, raspberry-pi

I went to go install ROS for my Rassberry Pi and found that there are 5 different variants. What is the difference between them and where can I go to learn about these differences for future updates?

Link to the ROSberryPi downloads I'm talking about:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Setting%20up%20ROS%20on%20RaspberryPi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing. I didn't realize they are in fact different distributions not variants. Also found the page where you can find out more about them: http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, XavierGuay! No need to be embarrassed - you found the answer to your question! You should be able to (after a day or two, if you can't right now) accept your own answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi suggests that we should be running ROS Kinetic on all the newer Raspberry Pis since it supports up to Buster with Raspberry Pi 4.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Stigma. Thanks for your answer but we are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation & context. Very short answers cannot do this, so please edit your answer to explain why it is right. Answers which don't include explanations may be removed. Also, links [tend to rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) rendering the answer useless if the linked content changes or disappears. Finally, please *[be nice](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)*. For specific guidelines, see our [Code of Conduct](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/conduct).